# It is known that 58% of homes in a certain suburb have large-screen TV sets. A random sample of eight homes is taken.

Tags: statistics

It is known that 58% of homes in a certain suburb have large-screen TV sets. A random sample of eight homes is taken.

a. Find the probability that exactly one home will have a large-screen TV set.

b. Find the probability that less than two homes will have a large-screen TV set.

c. Find the probability that at least two homes will have a large-screen TV set.

d. Find the mean and variance of this probability distribution.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we draw houses at random **with** replacement (if without then we need the exact number of homes, but the values with replacement will be good enough if there is thousands or more homes)

Let $X$ be the number of houses with a TV set in the sample and note $p=0.58$.

Then $X$ follows the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $\mathcal{B}(8,p)$

Which is :

$$\forall k\in [0,8], P(X=k) = \begin{pmatrix}8\\k\end{pmatrix}(1-p)^{8-k}p^k$$

With this we can easily solve your questions :

- $P(X=1) = \begin{pmatrix}8\\1\end{pmatrix}(1-p)^7p = 8(1-p)^7p$
- $P(X<2)=P(X=0) + P(X=1) = (1-p)^8+ 8(1-p)^7p$
- $P(X\ge 2) = 1 - P(X<2)$
- $E(X)=np=8\cdot 0.58$
- $var(X) = np(1-p) = 8\cdot0.58\cdot0.42$

The demonstrations for the mean and variance can be found on the wikipedia page.

I didn't perform the computations for each of these and I encourage you to try and understand what I wrote. As an exercice, try and find $P(X=4)$ and $P(X>6)$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are expected to get exact answers using the PDF (or PMF) formula
for the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 8, p = .58).$ The formulas given
in @Furrane's answer (+1) are special cases of that formula.

Here are exact answers from R statistical software, in which `dbinom` stands
for the binomial PDF and `pbinom` for the CDF. (Also `a:b` is shorthand for
the integers from $a$ through $b,$ where $b > a.$)

```
 dbinom(1, 8, .58)
 ## 0.01069703              # P(X = 1)
 pbinom(1, 8, .58)
 ## 0.01166529              # P(X <= 1) = P(X < 2)
 sum(dbinom(0:1, 8, .58))
 ## 0.01166529              # P(X <= 1) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1)
 1 - pbinom(1, 8, .58)
 ## 0.9883347               # P(X >= 2) = 1 - P(X <- 1)
 sum(dbinom(2:8, 8, .58))
 ## 0.9883347               # P(X >= 2) = P(X = 2) + P(X = 3) + ... P(X = 8)
```

Here is a bar chart of the distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(8, .58).$
Because $E(X) = \mu = 4.64$ and $SD(X) = \sigma = \sqrt{1.9488} = 1.3960,$
these binomial probabilities can be approximated by the distribution
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ the density function of which is shown as
a curve superimposed on the bar chart. I hope you will verify most of these
answers using formulas in your book and a calculator (or software).

[image]

*Note:* I you have not already done normal approximations to binomial probabilities,
I suppose you will do them soon: The area under this normal curve to the left of the vertical dotted line can be used to approximate $P(X \le 1) = P(X < 1.5) = P(X < 2).$ The computation is
$$P(X \le 1.5) = P\left(\frac{X=\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{1.5 - 4.64}{1.396}\right)
\approx P(Z < -2.18) = 0.0146,$$
where the numerical value can be found using printed tables of the standard
normal distribution. Above, we found the exact probability is $P(X < 2) = 0.0117.$ Normal approximations are often accurate to about two decimal places.
A somewhat closer normal approximation $0.01225$ can be obtained from software (which
avoids some rounding).

```
pnorm(1.5, 4.64, 1.3960)
## 0.01224723
```